How to configure Nginx as forward proxy server?
How to configure Nginx as a forward proxy server?
We have a requirement where we want to send all outbound traffic of a VM through a Nginx server.
Used the below configuration in the nginx server to achieve this scenario.

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;  # Google's DNS IP address for resolution

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name test-nginxproxyserver.com; # this is my nginx server domain name.


        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/nginx.crt;  # Path to your SSL certificate
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/nginx.key;  # Path to your SSL certificate key
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://$host$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            proxy_ssl_verify off;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        }
    }
}





Now from the client VM we have disabled it's all outbound requests and allowed only 443 port in the outbound request for nginx server domainName(test-nginxproxyserver.com) OR IP.
we have exported the below arguments from the Client vm
export http_proxy=http://test-nginxproxyserver.com:443
export https_proxy=https://test-nginxproxyserver.com:443


and running below command to test the setup
curl -x https://test-nginxproxyserver.com:443 https://google.com/

But it's throwing below error messages
curl: (56) CONNECT tunnel failed, response 400

Also tried to test the setup for apt update command with the below parameters added in the /etc/apt/apt.conf file.
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://test-nginxproxyserver.com:443/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://test-nginxproxyserver.com:443/";

But for this test as well it's throwing these error messages
root@Nginx-Client-VM:~# apt update
Ign:1 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble InRelease
Ign:2 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble-backports InRelease
Ign:4 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/security noble-security InRelease
Ign:1 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble InRelease
Ign:2 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble-backports InRelease
Ign:4 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/security noble-security InRelease
Ign:1 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble InRelease
Ign:2 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble-backports InRelease
Ign:4 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/security noble-security InRelease
Err:1 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble InRelease
  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)  Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2024 16:28:07 GMT  Content-Type: text/html  Content-Length: 166  Connection: close     [IP: xx.xx.xx.xx 443]
Err:2 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble-updates InRelease
  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)  Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2024 16:28:07 GMT  Content-Type: text/html  Content-Length: 166  Connection: close     [IP: xx.xx.xx.xx 443]
Err:3 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages noble-backports InRelease
  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)  Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2024 16:28:07 GMT  Content-Type: text/html  Content-Length: 166  Connection: close     [IP: xx.xx.xx.xx 443]
Err:4 https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/security noble-security InRelease
  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)  Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2024 16:28:07 GMT  Content-Type: text/html  Content-Length: 166  Connection: close     [IP: xx.xx.xx.xx 443]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
50 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages/dists/noble/InRelease  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)  Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2024 16:28:07 GMT  Content-Type: text/html  Content-Length: 166  Connection: close     [IP: xx.xx.xx.xx 443]
W: Failed to fetch https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages/dists/noble-updates/InRelease  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)  Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2024 16:28:07 GMT  Content-Type: text/html  Content-Length: 166  Connection: close     [IP: xx.xx.xx.xx 443]
W: Failed to fetch https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages/dists/noble-backports/InRelease  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)  Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2024 16:28:07 GMT  Content-Type: text/html  Content-Length: 166  Connection: close     [IP: xx.xx.xx.xx 443]
W: Failed to fetch https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/security/dists/noble-security/InRelease  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)  Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2024 16:28:07 GMT  Content-Type: text/html  Content-Length: 166  Connection: close     [IP: xx.xx.xx.xx 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


So how can we configure the nginx server to send all outbound traffic of a VM through it?
